# php - read paragraph change

Tags: php, arrays

The value in database is something like this:
(with paragrahs)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum purus eu finibus interdum.

    //new paragraph here

Sed sit amet libero leo. Ut laoreet enim nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin et purus nec augue porttitor fermentum.

    //new paragraph here

Fusce volutpat venenatis metus vitae scelerisque.
```

I have found this code to read each (non-word) symbol:

```
$str = 'Hello? My name is Ben! @ My age is 32.';
$arr = preg_split('/(\W)/', $str, null, 
  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but it will take space symbol as non-word too of course. How I will specify to seperate only when paragraph is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New line character is `\n` so you can just `explode` your string:

```
$result = explode("\n", $string);
var_dump($result);
```